# Right role authorization for a user to execute an aggregation pipeline with the $out operator

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to execute the below mongo aggregation pipeline, which writes the result set to a temporary collection inside the same db using MongoDB's `$out` operator. When I run this aggregation pipeline with a user having `readWrite` role, it fails with the following error, but when i update the user to have a role `dbOwner`, then it works as expected. So, my question: is there a lower privileged role to run this aggregation pipeline. 
I am not comfortable providing a `dbOwner` role to a user who just wants to execute an aggregation pipeline with `$out` operator, which 
 needs to create a collection, if it doesn't exist.

> 2017-07-13T23:27:23.324-0400 I ACCESS   [conn8216] Unauthorized: not
>   authorized on cfsa to execute command { aggregate:
>   "ap_line_item_details", pipeline: [ { $match: { XXX: { $in: [ "2161" ]
>   } } }, { $group: { _id: { XXX: { $toLower: "$XXX" }, XXX: { $toLower:
>   "$XXX" }, vendorName: { $toLower: "$XXX" } }, XXX: { $sum: "$XXX" },
>   spend: { $first: "$sumTotal" }, validGroups: { $addToSet: "$XXX" },
>   groupCount: { $sum: 1 }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX" },
>   XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX" }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX" },
>   XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX" }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX" },
>   valid_asList: { $addToSet: "$valid" }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX"
>   }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX" }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX"
>   }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX" }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX"
>   }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX" }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX"
>   }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet: "$XXX" }, XXX_asList: { $addToSet:
>   "$reason" }, XXX: { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "valid", "LOCKED" ]
>   }, then: "$XXX", else: 0 } } }, selectableCount: { $sum: { $cond: {
>   if: { $ne: [ "XXX", "LOCKED" ] }, then: 1, else: 0 } } } } }, {
>   $project: { XXX: "$_id.XXX", XXX: "$_id.XXX", XXX: "$_id.XXX",
>   XXX_asList: 1, XXX_asList: 1, XXX_asList: 1, XXX_asList: 1,
>   XXX_asList: 1, valid_asList: 1, XXX_asList: 1, XXX_asList: 1,
>   XXX_asList: 1, XXX_asList: 1, XXX_asList: 1, XXX_asList: 1,
>   XXX_asList: 1, XXX_asList: 1, XXX_asList: 1, validGroups: 1,
>   groupCount: 1, XXX: 1, selectableCount: 1, _id: 0, XXX: { $multiply: [
>   { $divide: [ "$XXX", 58066686.3353416 ] }, 100 ] }, XXX: "$XXX" } }, {
>   $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 200 }, { $sort: { XXX: -1 } }, { $out:
>   "temp_resultset_1" } ], allowDiskUse: true, bypassDocumentValidation:
>   true }

**UPDATE**: 
What initially looked like a flaky behavior on mongo's side, turns out to be more of a mongo's java drive issue. The above pipeline works fine if i execute it via mongo shell, but fails ( due to authorization issue) when submitted using java's driver using:

`mongoCollection
                    .aggregate(pipelineOperators)
                    .useCursor(false)
                    .allowDiskUse(true)
                    .bypassDocumentValidation(true)
                    .toCollection();`

Comment: `$out` "creates" a collection. Therefore [`createCollection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#createCollection) is required.

Comment: @NeilLunn, according to mongo docs (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#database-user-roles), `readWrite` role does allow `createCollection` action as well. Another interesting thing that i found was, the same aggregation pipeline works if i submit it via mongo shell, but it fails if i submit that aggregation pipeline via mongo's java driver.

Comment: @JasBali did you specify exact same command in the shell? In particular, `bypassDocumentValidation: true` is a separate permission, and if you didn't specify it in the shell that would explain why it worked there.